# Как добавить элемент к элементу словаря?

Tags: python, классы, словари, dict

У меня есть такой код:

```
class Throne:
  def __init__(self, fkg, fkggender):
    self.fkg = fkg
    self.wiknow = fkg
    self.all = dict()
    self.all[fkg] = fkggender
    self.alive = dict()
    self.alive[fkg] = True
    self.coup = list()
    self.parents = dict()
    self.children = [[[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)] for k in range(5)]

  def new_born(self, fpn, spn, kn1, Gen):
    if (fpn in self.all.keys()) and (spn in self.all.keys()):
      self.parents[fpn] = self.parents.get(fpn), kn1
      self.parents[spn] = self.parents.get(spn), kn1
      self.alive[kn1] = True
      self.all[kn1] = Gen
    else:
      print(fsn + ' and ' + ssn + ' are crooks!')
  def marry(self, fsn, ssn):
    if (fsn in self.all.keys()):
      self.all[ssn] = "F"
      self.alive[ssn] = True
      self.coup.append([fsn, ssn])
    elif (ssn in self.all.keys()):
      self.all[fsn] = 'M'
      self.alive[fsn] = True
      self.coup.append([fsn, ssn])
    else:
      print(fsn + ' and ' + ssn + ' are crooks!')

romanovy = Throne('Mihail Fedorov I', 'M')
romanovy.marry('Mihail Fedorov I', 'Evdokia')
romanovy.new_born('Mihail Fedorov I', 'Evdokia', 'Ilya', 'M')
romanovy.new_born('Mihail Fedorov I', 'Evdokia', 'Dima', 'M')
```

Больше ошибку не выдает, теперь в `new_born`

```
self.parents[fpn] = self.parents.get(fpn), kn1
self.parents[spn] = self.parents.get(spn), kn1
```

но в `parents` теперь лежит `{'Mihail Fedorov I': ((None, 'Ilya'), 'Dima'), 'Evdokia': ((None, 'Ilya'), 'Dima')}`
Как убрать скобки и оставить только `{'Mihail Fedorov I': 'Ilya', 'Dima', 'Evdokia': 'Ilya', 'Dima'}` где 2 элемента: `'Mihail Fedorov I': 'Ilya', 'Dima'` и `'Evdokia': 'Ilya', 'Dima'`

Comment: скопируйте полный текст ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Интик это он и есть

Comment: Интик вот все что выдалось:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-9-2b08b146e815> in new_born(self, fpn, spn, kn1, Gen)
     27   def new_born(self, fpn, spn, kn1, Gen):
     28     if (fpn in self.all.keys()) and (spn in self.all.keys()):
---> 29       self.parents[fpn] = [self.parents[fpn], kn1]
     30       self.parents[spn] = kn1
     31       self.alive[kn1] = True

KeyError: 'Mihail Fedorov I'

Comment: под вашим вопросом есть кнопка править, текст ошибки вставьте в вопрос. и покажите содержимое  self.parents

Answer (score 0):

По порядку:

```
romanovy = Throne('Mihail Fedorov I', 'M')
```

при инициализации экземпляра класса Вы создаете пустой словарь `self.parents = dict()`

```
romanovy.marry('Mihail Fedorov I', 'Evdokia')
```

Далее выполняете метод, который никак не затрагивает его содержимое.

```
romanovy.new_born('Mihail Fedorov I', 'Evdokia', 'Ilya', 'M')
```

А в следующем методе присваиваете ему список, где первый элемент пытаетесь достать из словаря (а он пуст) `self.parents[fpn] = [self.parents[fpn], kn1]`.
Попробуйте через `self.parents.get(fpn, <значение_если_ключа_нет>)`, либо если словарь пустой вообще не передавайте его в list.

**update**:
Для добавления имен используйте список/кортеж, что бы не городить лишнюю логику можно использовать изначально в `__init__` - `self.parents = defaultdict(list)`, тогда можно без блока `if`

```
        if not self.parents.get(fpn) and not self.parents.get(spn):
            self.parents[fpn] = []
            self.parents[spn] = []
        self.parents[fpn].append(kn1)
        self.parents[spn].append(kn1)
```

Comment: Это не совсем то что я хотел сделать. Я хотел сделать чтобы к словарю ```parents``` добавлялся элемент ```fpn``` внутри у которого лежал элемент ```kn1```

Comment: @lebedlebedev дополнил

Comment: Спасибо, но когда я в ```__init__``` использую ```self.parents = defaultdict(list)```, мне выдает ошибку:
```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable```

Comment: Спасибо, использовал ```if```, все работает